# Can I safely use `spread` to copy from an array slice into the same array?

Tags: fortran

I have 2D data stored in a file that I want to load and spread into a 3D array over the last index.
Can I safely load the data into a slice and then use spread from this, like so:

```
real, dimension(nx,ny,nz) :: data

call load_some_data(data(:,:,1))

data = spread(data(:,:,1), 3, nz)
```

Or do I need a temporary 2D array for spread to be standard conforming?
Would the `spread` call also work in an OpenMP `workshare`-clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. Depending on the level of compiler optimizations it will or will not use a temporary array, but it is legal.

No, it won't be parallelized in the `workshare` construct. A simple array assignment will be, but I fear that the function result will be problematic. And the call to `spread` will certainly be serial.